# Yii Hybridauth integration

Tags: authentication, integration, hybridauth

I follow everything by referring this http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/userguide/Configuration.html. Think to see the example first before integrate but none of the examples success to open. It prompt me this error msg

Notice: unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Error at offset 0 of 1 bytes in C:\mysite\hybridauth\Hybrid\Storage.php on line 33

How to solve this error?

this is my config array look like:

> return    array(      "base_url" => "mylocalhost/hybridauth/",
>
> ```
>   "providers" => array (              // openid providers             "OpenID" => array
> ```
>
> (
>                 "enabled" => false          ),
>
> ```
>       "AOL"  => array ( 
>           "enabled" => false              ),
>
>       "Yahoo" => array ( 
>           "enabled" => false,
>           "keys"    => array ( "id" => "", "secret" => "" )           ),
>
>       "Google" => array ( 
>           "enabled" => false,
>           "keys"    => array ( "id" => "", "secret" => "" )           ),
>
>       "Facebook" => array ( 
>           "enabled" => true,
>           "keys"    => array ( "id" => "XXXXXXXX", "secret" => "XXXXX" )          ),
>
>       "Twitter" => array ( 
>           "enabled" => true,
>           "keys"    => array ( "key" => "XXXXX", "secret" => "XXXXX" )            ),
>
>       // windows live             "Live" => array ( 
>           "enabled" => false,
>           "keys"    => array ( "id" => "", "secret" => "" )           ),
>
>       "MySpace" => array ( 
>           "enabled" => false,
>           "keys"    => array ( "key" => "", "secret" => "" )              ),
>
>       "LinkedIn" => array ( 
>           "enabled" => false,
>           "keys"    => array ( "key" => "", "secret" => "" )              ),
>
>       "Foursquare" => array (
>           "enabled" => false,
>           "keys"    => array ( "id" => "", "secret" => "" )           ),      ),
>
>   // if you want to enable logging, set 'debug_mode' to true  then
> ```
>
> provide a writable file by the web server on "debug_file"
>         "debug_mode" => false,
>
> ```
>   "debug_file" => ""  );
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This is the recommended pluging for HybridAuth in Yii: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/hoauth/
Also make sure you have the newest version of HybridAuth from the GitHub repository: https://github.com/hybridauth/hybridauth as this looks like a problem that was already fixed.